# Xamarin, How to check in xaml if bindable property exist?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

In my xaml I'm using q converter that checks `AlarmStatus` for `true` or `false`. It works fine when the user edits an existing Alarm, but when the user creates a new alarm then the property `AlarmStatus` doesn't exist and the background colour is not set.
Is it possible to check in xaml if the property `AlarmStatus` exist? If not then color should be set to red.

```cs
public class AlarmModel
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public DateTime TimeCreate { get; set; }

    public DateTime AlarmTime { get; set; }
    public bool AlarmStatus { get; set; }

}
```

```cs
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class AlarmView : TabbedPage
{
    private AlarmModel CurrentAlarm;

    //if user create a new alarm then no argument pass in constructor
    public AlarmView (AlarmModel alarm = null)
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        if (alarm != null)
        {
            this.CurrentAlarm = alarm;                         
        }

        BindingContext = CurrentAlarm;

    }
}
```

```xaml
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Entry  x:Name="titleInput" Text="{Binding Title}" HeightRequest="50" FontSize="20"/>               
            <Editor x:Name="contentInput" Text="{Binding Content}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
            <Button Text="Start" BackgroundColor="{Binding AlarmStatus,Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}}" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
</StackLayout>
```

```cs
class ColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(value==null)return Color.Black;

        bool b = ((bool)value);
        return b ? Color.Green : Color.Red;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the converter

Comment: I added but first part of code gone, some reason.

Comment: What color you want it to be if null? So far the code reflects what you describe in the question. It will return black if value is null. This means that `AlarmStatus` is a nullable boolean

Comment: No, it doesn't return black.

Comment: Why are you then trying to bind a property that does not exist?

Comment: Read my description. Is the same template for "edit" and "add new alarm" page.

Comment: How could the property not exist for new alarm. Are they not using the same model?

Comment: Please clarify if that correct: Doesn't exist - Red, True - Green, False - which color?

Comment: For edit is using selected alarm as a binding context.

Comment: Doesn't exist - Black, True - Green, False - Red

Comment: @Klick provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce your problem. Right now your explanation of the issue is not clear. What does the model that is being bound to look like?

Comment: You can change desire colors in converter provided

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean with “does not exist”? Is it unset or is this a different datatype that actually has no `AlarmStatus` property? You’re being vague here and the question is definitely missing a [mcve] to understand what’s actually going on.

Comment: @poke As I understand it can be 2 cases. 1. Property exist but null. 2. Property comes from JSON, so it may be doesn't exist but when you desirialize it to model it will still be null. So, assuming null for doesn't exist should be correct approach. Is that right Klick?

Comment: @YuriS Where a values comes from does not matter at all. The language has default values for members. Also, it’s very unlikely that *adding* a new alarm on the UI does involve any JSON. And it’s completely *not* clear whether the `AlarmStatus` property is nullable or not. We know nothing and the information OP has given so far is somewhat contradictory, so I would suggest you to wait until OP clarifies the question. As it stands right now, the question is not properly answerable, and I’m voting to close as off-topic, for not including enough information.

Comment: @poke sure, it is your right to vote but I would still try to help the person and not to be so hard. At least give him a chance to clarify. He is not replying may be because he went to sleep already :-) Not every one is on the same time zone :-)

Comment: @YuriS Closing a question is not an absolute decision. Right now, the question is not clear enough, so the correct thing to do is to have it put on-hold. If OP comes back and clarifies it, the question can always be reopened.

Comment: @poke Sure, agree

Comment: OK. Sorry for not clear explanation. I will add more information tomorrow. Thank you.

Comment: so, my answer didn't work for you?

Comment: I added more code, alarm model, code behind part of xaml. My question is why converter doesn't work when "AlarmStatus" is null.

Comment: @Klick check update. The problem was that you were not assigning a model to bind to.

Answer (score 0):

Update the `AlarmModel.AlarmStatus` property to be nullable boolean ie `bool?` to allow for the three states you described.

```
public class AlarmModel {
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public DateTime TimeCreate { get; set; }

    public DateTime AlarmTime { get; set; }
    public bool? AlarmStatus { get; set; } //<-- needs to be nullable for 3 states
}
```

The converter would expect then a `bool?`

```
public class ColorConverter : IValueConverter {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        var status = (bool?) value;
        if (status == null) return Color.Black;                
        return status.Value ? Color.Green : Color.Red;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You also need to make sure there is a model to bind to when creating new alarm.

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class AlarmView : TabbedPage {
    private AlarmModel CurrentAlarm;

    //if user create a new alarm then no argument pass in constructor
    public AlarmView (AlarmModel alarm = null) {
        InitializeComponent ();
        if (alarm != null) {
            this.CurrentAlarm = alarm;                         
        }
        BindingContext = CurrentAlarm ?? new AlarmModel(); //Must have a model to bind to.
    }
}
```

You were not assigning a binding context which meant there was nothing for the view to bind to. If no model was provided you have to create one for the view to bind to and get the desired behavior.

Comment: It still works only when value is true or false. If property doesn't exist background colour is default gray colour.

Comment: It will not return Black because if it doesn't exist you set it to false which means Red

Comment: So you saying that you want it to return black when null? That was not the impression i Got from the question, which is why I removed it.

Comment: Based on the last sentence in the question, you indicated that you want if the property is does not have a value then return red.

Comment: @Nikosi He wants 3 colors

Comment: @Klick you were not assigning a binding context which meant there was nothing to bind to. If no model was provided you have to create one for the view to bind to and get the desired behavior.

Comment: Thank you to explain me what was wrong but still I'm struggle to return 3 different colors. One for null, second for true and third for false.if (value == null) { return Color.Black; } doesn't work.

Comment: @Klick, It can't work because in your example you have `AlarmStatus` as bool which means it can never be null unless you change it to be nullable. I misunderstood the original requirement for the 3 states. The above updated question should now solve the problem.

Comment: Now VS throwing a error: "An unhandled exception occurred."

Comment: Where is it throwing the error? Remember your Value controller remains as you originally had it. Update the model and view like in the answer. You are dealing with a bool? so your code needs to cater for the possibility of it being null.

Comment: Error is throwing when I try to create new Alarm. I updated model and view and my converter is:  if ((bool?)value == null) { return Color.Black; }
            bool b = (bool)(value);
            return b ? Color.Green : Color.Red;

Comment: What line specifically. that last comment was too broad to isolate the problem

Answer (score 0):

Implemented change of alarm status every button click. True - Green, False - Red, Doesn't exist - Black.

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ButtonRendererDemo;assembly=ButtonRendererDemo"
             x:Class="ButtonRendererDemo.ValueConverterPage">

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:ColorConverter x:Key="colorConvert"></local:ColorConverter>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Button Text="Click me" BackgroundColor="{Binding AlarmStatus, Converter={StaticResource colorConvert}}" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**Code behind:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace ButtonRendererDemo
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class ValueConverterPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ValueConverterPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = this;
        }

        bool? alarmStatus = null;
        public bool? AlarmStatus
        {
            get
            {
                return alarmStatus;
            }
            set
            {
                alarmStatus = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("AlarmStatus");
            }
        }

        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            switch (AlarmStatus)
            {
                case true:
                    AlarmStatus = false;
                    break;
                case false:
                    AlarmStatus = null;
                    break;
                case null:
                    AlarmStatus = true;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public class ColorConverter : IValueConverter
    {

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            switch (value as bool?)
            {
                case true:
                    return Color.Green;
                case false:
                    return Color.Red;
                case null:
                default:
                    return Color.Black;
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

    }
}
```